# Shareable angular component

Tags: angular

Given this app structure:

- Module 1
- Module 2
- Module 3
- Module 4
- Shared

  - Shared component 1
  - Shared component 2

So I need to create a "shared component" that I know it will just be shared between Modules 1 and 2 and can't be used anywhere else. Should I create it as a normal shared component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add the shared module to the imports array of the other modules, those components won't be shared with the other modules.

For example:

My ProductModule includes SharedModule in its imports:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, 
    RouterModule.forChild([...])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductDetailComponent,
    ProductEditComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductService
  ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

So only the Product Module's components can access the shared module's components.

Any module that should not use the Shared Module, don't add it to it's imports array.

Comment: I'm talking about a shared component, not shared modules. I don't think this new component should be with all the other shared components as it's a shared component with "restrictions"

Comment: There is no way to share a component without having it in a module. So I don't understand what you are looking for. Could you expand upon your question and provide more detail on what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "shared component"?

Answer (score 0):

DeborahK's answer is right but per your comment, I believe you didn't really get it so here is further elaboration.

To share a component between Module 1 and Module 2, you will have to create a Shared Module. In the `exports` array of the shared module, you'll export the component you would want to share. Now, in the `imports` array of the Module 1 and Module 2, you will import the Shared Module. This way, the exported component will be available for both Module 1 and Module 2.

Your app structure will look like something like this.

- Module 1
- Module 2
- Module 3
- Module 4
- Shared (folder)

  - Shared Module
  - Shared component 1
  - Shared component 2

In the `shared.module.ts`, you'd have something like this.

```
exports: [SharedComponent]
```

In the `module1.ts` and `module2.ts`, you also have something like this.

```
imports:[SharedModule]
```

Comment: Maybe the question is not well explained, I already have a SharedModule with shared components on it, the question was were to put a component that can't be shared across the whole application but can just be shared between two modules.